# Connect Postgres db hosted in azure storage using docker

Tags: postgresql, azure, networking, flyway

I am trying to connect the postgres database hosted in azure storage account from within the flyway, flyway is running as docker image in docker container

`docker run --rm flyway/flyway -url=jdbc:postgresql://postgres-azure-db:5432/postgres -user=user -password=password info` but I am getting the error **ERROR: Unable to obtain connection from database**

Any idea/doc-link would be helpful

Comment: If that the entirety  of the error message?

Comment: This is stacktrace
`Caused by: org.postgresql.util.PSQLException: The connection attempt failed.
Caused by: java.net.SocketTimeoutException: connect timed out`

Comment: I am able to connect to postgress installed on my localhost from within docker, but if I am tryin to connect to posgres hosted on Azure that time unable to connect

Comment: Sounds like a firewall.  They block you not by actively rejecting the connection, but just by ghosting you, leading to timeouts.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After exploring few option, I implemented the flyway using the Azure container  instance. Create an ACI to store the flyway docker image and to execute the commands inside ACI, Also created a file share to keep the config file and sql scripts.

All these resource (Storage, ACI, file share) I created via the terraform scripts which is being triggered from Jenkins.

Answer (score 1):

You have a similar error (different context, same general solution) in [this flyway issue](https://github.com/flyway/flyway/issues/3377)

> my missing piece for reaching private Cloud SQL instances from private worker pools in Cloud Build was a missing network route.
> The fix is ensuring the Service Networking VPC peer has the "Export custom routes" setting enabled, and that the Cloud Router advertises the route.

In your context (Azure), see "[Quickstart: Use Azure Data Studio to connect and query PostgreSQL](https://Quickstart:%20Use%20Azure%20Data%20Studio%20to%20connect%20and%20query%20PostgreSQL)"

You can also try with a [local Postgres instance first, and Azure Data Studio](https://aaronwinters.com/managing-heroku-postgres-with-azure-data-studio-and-flyway-part-1/), for testing.